# pg_tileserv Docker - How to access and modify the configuration file?

Tags: vector-tiles, docker, pg-tileserv

I set up pg_tileserv. Once using the binary file and once using Docker. Downloading the binary includes a config .toml file. How can I access this file when I set up pg_tileserv with Docker? There are only the pull and run statement given.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so this is more of a docker question than a GIS question and probably should have been placed on stackoverflow. Anyway, you probably want to mount the config file into the docker container. I've got a docker-compose file I use to fire up pg_featureserv but not pg_tileserv. All of these commands are usable in straight a docker command but I find docker-compose a little more expressive.

What this compose file says is fire up a container called featserv using the docker image pramsey/pg_featureserv:latest from docker-hub. Map port 9000 on the host machine to 9000 on the container. Also copy the edited config file "./config/my_pg_featureserv.toml" file to "/config/pg_featureserv.toml" inside the container.

```
version: '3.7'
#-----------------
docker-compose.yaml file to fire up database API.
#-----------------

services:
  featserv: 
    image: pramsey/pg_featureserv:latest
    ports:
      - 9000:9000 
    volumes:
      - ./config/my_pg_featureserv.toml:/config/pg_featureserv.toml
```

This is equivalent to something like:

```
docker run -p 9000:9000 -v /config/my_pg_featureserv.toml:/config/pg_featureserv.toml pramsey/pg_featureserv:latest
```

also take a look here: https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But where to put the config file on the file system? My Docker (Desktop) is installed on Windows but using WSL2.

Comment: Docker on windows is pretty painful especially when it comes to mounted volumes. I can't really help you with this, when I need to run docker on a windows machine I stick it in a linux VM. Generally speaking, you should keep the config file somewhere near the docker-compose.yaml file. In my example above it would be in a sub-folder called config placed next to the yaml file

Comment: I have Docker run on WSL2, so it could be compared to a linux VM?
Do you know how I could specify my config file using the Docker Desktop GUI? There is the section "Volumes" with "Host path" and "Container path", but I cannot get it to work to put somewhere my configuration .toml file.